# "One knows not whether to laugh or cry" is it correct grammar?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I was reading the [News](https://www.thequint.com/opinion/2017/06/01/rajasthan-hc-judge-cow-the-national-animal) and confused about this sentence : **One knows not whether to laugh or cry**

> Reading Justice Mahesh Chandra Sharma’s recent judgment, one knows not
>   whether to laugh or cry. It is certainly a first in judicial history.

Is this sentence correct or not? If yes, what is the rule applied here?

I mean it should be : No one knows or One does not know.

Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One knows not whether to laugh or cry
>   One does not know whether to laugh or cry

are both correct, understandable, and can be said

Some may point out that putting the "*not*" after the verb sounds antiquated, more like Yoda-speak

> Do or do **not**, there is not try.

It is a matter of style.

The usual idiomatic saying is

> I don't know whether to laugh or cry

meaning that something is so *outlandish* or *preposterous* it can be viewed as either *humorous* or *tragic*.

A related saying is

> If I wasn't laughing, I'd be crying

Answer (score 0):

"one knows not" seems like a direct translation from German where you would say "man weiss es nicht". I wouldn't use this in English. One doesn't know is better and sounds right.

Comment: This use is not idiomatic, but it is still proper.